# Linear dependency of polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra

Find all real numbers k such that the polynomials 
$1+kx+kx^2$,
$k+x+kx^2$,
$k+kx+x^2$
are linearly independent.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you consider expressing this in terms of rank of a matrix, by using a basis for the polynomials in $x$ of degree at most $2$?  Some show of effort to solve this problem would help Readers better understand what difficulty you are having.

Answer (score 2):

Linear dependence means there is $a,b,c$ not all $0$ such that
$$a(1+kx+kx^2)+b(k+x+kx^2)+c(k+kx+x^2)=0$$
rewrite as
$$(a+bk +ck)+(ak+b+ck)x+ (ak+bk+c)x^2=0$$
thus we need to solve
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1&k&k\\
k&1&k\\
k&k&1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
a\\
b\\
c
\end{bmatrix}=0$$
The non trivial solution exists if and only if 
$$\mathrm{Det}
\left(\begin{bmatrix}
1&k&k\\
k&1&k\\
k&k&1
\end{bmatrix}
\right)=2 k^3-3 k^2+1=\left(k+\frac{1}2\right)(k-1)^2=0$$

Thus, for $k\ne-\frac{1}2,1$ the given polynomials are linearly independent.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

In the basis $\{1,x,x^2 \}$ your polynomials ar represented by the vectors $(1,k,k)^T$, $(k,1,k)^T$, $(k,k,1)^T$, and these are linearly **dependent** iff 
$$
\det
\begin{bmatrix}
1&k&k\\
k&1&k\\
k&k&1
\end{bmatrix}
=0
$$
and this gives: $2k^3-3k^2+1=(k-1)^2(2k+1)=0$